# How to disable page boosts when indexing?

Tags: solr, nutch

Nutch by default enables the `scoring-opic` plugin. From my understanding, the scoring plugin is responsible for setting the score of each url in the crawldb. This score will be used in two ways:

1. During the generation of a new segment (fetch list) with `-topN`, the score determines which urls will be part of the fetch list (those urls with the highest scores will be part of the fetch list).
2. During indexing into Solr using the `indexer-solr` plugin, the score will be used to set the boost of the document indexed into Solr.

Please correct me if I am wrong about any of the above.

For my use case:

1. I want to disable boosts when indexing into Solr.
2. As I am crawling only a few URLs, and I do not want links from/to outside each individual URL to affect the score. For example, if there is a link from `http://siteA.com` to `http://siteB.com`, `siteB`'s score should **not** be affected. Whereas if there is a link from `http://siteA.com/first` to `http://siteA.com/second`, I want the score for `http://siteA.com/second` to increase.

What setting can I tweak to accomplish these two goals?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question you could remove the `boost` field from the Solr Index Writer mapping (take a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/nutch/IndexWriters#Mapping_section). This should avoid sending the field to Solr.

Regarding the URL scoring for internal/external links, you could try changing the scoring config in the `nutch-site.xml` file. By default, both internal/external links are set to 1.